# Any better way to design this Database structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a `product` table which stores the information of a product. I have ***Only one*** `Reference Product` which have the same properties as of a product.

My doubt is what is the best way to store the information of `Reference Product`

**Case1:** Have a `Reference_Flag` in the `Product` table.

**PRODUCT**
Product_ID: Long
ReferenceFlag: Boolean

Clean way however...

**Disadvantage**:

1) As per the requirements only one `reference product` is possible, however this DB structure allows more than one.

2) As there could be only one `reference product`. I have to unnecssarly set `Reference_Flag` to `0` for other products in my table. Therefore as the data increases, memory is not used properly (Can't say whether it is a valid case or not)

---

**Case2:** Have a seperate table which stores only `Reference product`.

**PRODUCT**
Product_ID: Long

**REFERENCE_PRODUCT**
Ref_ID: Long
Product_ID: Long

In the `REFERNCE_PRODUCT` table I will have only one row. It will solve the problem of memory utilization and I can restrict the table to have only one row.

However now I have two tables.

---

Which way is better or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use the product with `id=0` (or similar) as reference product?

Comment: you mean to say, I can reserve an ID for the `reference product`. So simple and clean... thanks :)